# How to only allow 3 dates to be selected C# webforms calendar

Tags: c#, webforms, calendar

I'm trying to make a webform on C# to select a party date. I'm wondering of there is a way to make only 3 specific dates selectable on the calendar.

Comment: why not putting the 3 dates in a comboBox to select the date there?

Comment: It's for class, I cannot use a comboBox or radioButtons